# Small gear or medium gear for Jenkins Server on Openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

For setup Jenkins on Openshift you have to create an application a Jenkins Server. In the web console you can choose which type of gear Small or Medium.

What is the recommended gear type Small/Medium for a Jenkins Server on Openshift?

Comment: The only difference appears to be RAM size. So it will just depend on your implementation.

Comment: This is not a question of opinion at all - it's a question of the resources required to build a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key quantity is not the size of the jenkins application, but the size of the gear jenkins creates to build your application.  The Jenkins integration in OpenShift allows you to offload the build of your application into a separate gear which is created by the Jenkins job set up for your application.  Currently, the size of the builder gear is set to small in the jenkins job configuration that's created.  This config is user-owned, so you can change it by editting config.xml in `app-root/data/jobs/<your application name>-build`, but your domain will need to be able to create larger gears in order for it to work.

Comment: Nice to know about Config.xml.